# After replacing my Moen cartridge in the shower I got water hammer in the wall

Tags: plumbing, water-hammer

I replaced my shower cartridge and after turning the water back on I got water hammer which sounded in the wall every time i turned any water in that part of the house on or especially off! I've never had this issue before and it would bang up to 5 times after shutting the water off in anywhere in this bathroom or the other bathroom which is on the other side of the wall.
I drained all the pipes several times to replenish the air stops but nothing helped. I talked to a few plumbers and no one could figure it out...

GOOD NEWS!!! after reading another post about someone halving trouble with a Danco replacement I went out and bought a Moen cartridge and the water hammer went away! now it works perfect!!
Must have been the cheap/faulty Danco cartridge